# How to output each model output in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a collection of models which I am looping through to template out using Handlebars. I would like to add the index number to each output model but I'm not sure how this is done, I've tried `@index` and `@key` with no success, can anyone recommend what I need to do?

**Collection snippet:**

```
dataStore.searchResultsCollection = new PlaylistCollection([
        {
            'id': 'h5EofwRzit0',
            'artist': 'Daft Punk',
            'song_name': 'Get Lucky (Official Audio)',
            'video_id': 'h5EofwRzit0',
            'video_author': 'DaftPunkVEVO',
            'video_description': 'Random Access Memories, in stores now: iTunes: http://smarturl.it/RAMiTunes Amazon (CD/LP): http://smarturl.it/ram-amazon Direct (CD/LP): http://www.myplaydi...',
            'video_img': 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5NV6Rdv1a3I/default.jpg',
            'likes': '874413',
            'dislikes': '28789'
        } ...
```

**Handlebars snippet**

```
    <p class="item-delete js-delete-video" data-id="{{id}}" id="{{id}}">delete</p>
    <p class="item-title js-play-video" data-id="{{id}}" id="{{id}}" data-index="{{@index}}" title="{{artist}} - {{song_name}}">{{artist}} - {{song_name}}</p>
```

**Output template looks like this:**

```
<li><p class="item-delete js-delete-video" data-id="h5EofwRzit0" id="h5EofwRzit0">delete</p>
    <p class="item-title js-play-video" data-id="h5EofwRzit0" data-song="Get Lucky (Official Audio)" id="h5EofwRzit0" data-index="" title="Daft Punk - Get Lucky (Official Audio)">Daft Punk - Get Lucky (Official Audio)</p>
    </li>
```

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/qs5XT/) Fiddle is working as desired.

Comment: Can you show HOW are you passing the data to Handlebars?